# I have a problem with Django, with the manage.py file

Tags: python, django

I just began with Django, I'm following the steps of a youtube tutorial, but when I want to run this command:

```py
python manage.py runserver
```

This is the error message:

```py
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x03E82780>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Personal\Dev\cfehome\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Personal\Dev\cfehome\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "D:\Personal\Dev\cfehome\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 251, in raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "D:\Personal\Dev\cfehome\lib\site-packages\django\utils\six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "D:\Personal\Dev\cfehome\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Personal\Dev\cfehome\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "D:\Personal\Dev\cfehome\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "D:\Personal\Dev\cfehome\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 94, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "D:\Personal\Dev\cfehome\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "D:\Personal\Dev\cfehome\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.admin.filters import (
  File "D:\Personal\Dev\cfehome\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\filters.py", line 10, in <module>
    from django.contrib.admin.options import IncorrectLookupParameters
  File "D:\Personal\Dev\cfehome\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 12, in <module>
    from django.contrib.admin import helpers, widgets
  File "D:\Personal\Dev\cfehome\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\widgets.py", line 151
    '%s=%s' % (k, v) for k, v in params.items(),
    ^
SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesized
```

Do someone know how can I solve this error?

Comment: Try to update Django `pip install -U django`

Comment: Thanks, it works

Answer (score 0):

Follow the path in Your Django App

```
D:\Personal\Dev\cfehome\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\widgets.py
```

Next step in line no.151 :

```
('%s=%s' % (k, v) for k, v in params.items())
```

You must have to parenthesize this.

Comment: You should not edit the Django source code. Especially if you're a beginner.

Comment: solution is given in comments: updating django fixes the issue